# Is $100x^2+20x$ a factorial?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, factorial

In this equation , $$100x^2+20x =m! $$where $x$ and $m$ are integers arethere infinite results of this to be true. 
It may be easier to think that when $m! = 1-9$ can be solved easily $$m!>9 $$
so that
$$m!=1×2×3×4×5×6×7×8×9×10\times\ldots×m!$$
Given the equation  $$100x^2+20x=m!$$
$$20(5x^2+x)=m!$$
$$5x^2+x=\frac{m!}{20}$$
And $\dfrac{m!}{20} \bmod 5 =0$

Answer (score 3):

Take $y = 10x + 1$, the equation becomes $y^2 = m! + 1$ and reduce to a special case of an open problem ( [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard's_problem) ).

As of this moment, only three solutions for $(m,y)$ is known.  $(4,5)$, $(5,11)$ and $(7,71)$. This leads to two solutions of current problem $(m,x) = (5,1)$ and $(7,7)$.

Look at the wiki page and references there for more info.

Comment: This was one of the paths in how I try to solve brocard's problem. Do you have any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: @PintOfMilk No idea, if this is the motivation behind your question, you definitely should mention that in your question.

Comment: Yeah I apologise. I was thinking that one could use that fact that factorial have prime numbers in them. Dividing an approximation of a primorial over a factorial could mean that because $$100x^2+20x $$ is a factor of X that means that if for example that $$100x^2+20x$$ is over the lower bound of an approximation of a primorial divided by a factorial.